# Officejet 5610 prints blank pages in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, printer

I'm trying to get my HP Officejet 5610 working on Ubuntu 10.04.  It installed just fine, and when I print I hear the print head moving, but the page is blank.  It works just fine on a windows machine.  Any ideas?  I'm a Linux noob so I apologize in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem with my HP Officejet 5610xi, which probably uses the same driver.  I initially tried use a printer share on my Windows Vista box, where my 5610xi is normally connected, and got the same symptoms: print head activity, but page always blank.

I went to [this](http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/index.html) site and downloaded the latest driver file for the 5610xi (even though they claim support for the printer is already in Ubuntu).  I then followed the steps to extract the .ppd file from it, and use that to add the printer locally (Sysyem -> Administration -> Printing).  That didn't seem to fix my printing over the network, but I can now print to the printer connected locally to my Ubuntu 10.04 laptop using USB.